# MGLS_ASYNCH Processes are checking out multiple licenses

Tags: calibre, flexlm

I am firing Calibre(v 2013.4_37.29) runs from a server.
But I see that, there are multiple licenses checked out by my name and few are getting queued, when I fire runs.
On a deeper look I see that there are multiple mgls_async processes running which might be checking out the licenses. When I kill them, I am able to free up the licenses.

Any idea whats going on? Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Calibre' is a commercial name. In Calibre you have many functions or stage. It could be have no link between a commercial name and the resources needed to fulfil each stage.

'Calibre' use a licenses service from you own computer or from a specific computer on your network. The licences service use a specific file given by Mentor.
The structure and the contents of the licences file has no relationship with the a commercial name, your are in this case. And for each stage of your work with Calibre, you use (without know it probably) some specific 'features'.

At a stage, some resources are associated. In the license file that you don't see, a resource could be : 'INCREMENT', 'FEATURE' or 'PACKAGE'. For example, if a resource is defined as a 'PACKAGE', when you use it, you get one or more tokens from the 'INCREMENT' resources that compose the 'PACKAGE' : you use simultaneously a (or more than one) token from many 'INCREMENT'.
So, at each stage, you have many requests to the licenses server and many process could be launched to fulfil the stage in your use of 'Calibre'.

It's the editor of the software that decide how each function or stage is split in 'INCREMENT', 'FEATURE' or 'PACKAGE'.

The licenses service is composed of two daemons : 'lmgrd' and what is called the 'daemon vendor'. When the soft (for you 'Calibre') must use a resource, it sends a request to 'lmgrd'. 'lmgrd' make some controls and pass the request to the 'daemon vendor'. At this moment, I can't check it, but I know that the name of the 'daemon vendor' of Mentor is something like 'mgls...'.

This a rough description of the use of a software associated with a licenses server of type 'Flexnet' (the old name is 'Flexlm') from the Flexera company.

To fulfil a stage, in function of the software implementation, one or many process could launched, in your case with your login for owner.
As you as seen, when you kill your process, the token(s) associated to each process are freed.

But in a normal situation, when the stage is fulfil, the process disappeared and the token are freed without any intervention.